# Is there a maximum number of pages that you can import using the importPage() function?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am attempting to download a document that I have generated but I receive a long list of duplicate errors.

> Warning: fseek(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /public_html/vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/PdfParser/StreamReader.php on line 409
>
> Warning: fread(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /public_html/vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/PdfParser/StreamReader.php on line 412

This does not happen with other downloads only when there are lots of other PDFs imported into the download. Has anyone come across this issue?

**Troubleshooting so far**

- The Error is not reflective of what's happening - I think!
- Tested each file import individually and works fine.
- The file is named correctly, has the correct path and not corrupt.
- Removed other documents and it appears to be a number of imports issue.
- MPDF Version is 8.0

```
$pagecount = $mpdf->setSourceFile('pdf-forms/FileName.pdf');
    for ($i = 1; $i <= ($pagecount); $i++) {
                $mpdf->AddPage('P');
                if ($i == 1) {

                    $html = '<h3 style="color: #ffffff;">File Title</h3>';
                    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                }
                $import_page = $mpdf->importPage($i);
                $mpdf->useTemplate($import_page);
            }
```

The above loop can rund upto 45 times which imports on average 5 pages per import.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the exact same issue. When I increase the number of imported PDF files it crashes.
PHP Warning:  feof(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /var/www/vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/PdfParser/StreamReader.php on line 464
PHP Stack trace:

PHP  27. setasign\\Fpdi\\PdfParser\\StreamReader->increaseLength() /var/www/vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/PdfParser/Tokenizer.php:130

PHP  28. feof() /var/www/vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/PdfParser/StreamReader.php:464